# query integer field thousand separator in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

how should I write an elasticsearch query where one of the fields is an integer field and sometimes users enter a number with thousand seperators/commas?

or is this something that needs to be dealt with when indexing the data?

Answer (score 0):

> or is this something that needs to be dealt with when indexing the data?

This. You should deal with these kind of data discrepancies prior to even sending the data to Elasticsearch.

Beware: some locales (e.g., European) use `,` to represent `.`. Therefore blind replacement may not be a safe decision, depending on your use case. There's naturally tons of other variants too, but knowing your use case really helps to make it simple.

So while I read `100000` as `100,000`, many cultures may read it as `100.000`. This has a pretty serious impact on decimal points too because `100000.123` is hard to distinguish -- did they forget to put the other `.` or is that just a decimal point (probably the latter).

The point is that you need to know the data's source to make the correct, locale dependent adjustment here.

Comment: It's not really anything specific to Elasticsearch (or any other data store). [MSDN actually has a pretty good writeup on the topic here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb688127.aspx).

Comment: Agreed, this needs to be handled at indexing time in order to make sure the data is standardized and exempt from any locale specific quirks.

Comment: Is this how I should solve the problem: generate a new string based field with the commas/separators in the numbers and just match both fields when searching?